# Populate multi-select field with saved data from linking table [uiComponent]

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent

I have a multi-select field to link an entity (specialist) to multiple product categories. The field shows and the selected categories are saved when I check them: [image: Screenshot initial state]

If I check the database, the records are saved successfully. However, if I refresh the page, the items don't show. If I check these items again and click save, it inserts duplicate records in the linking table.

I don't know where to look to fix this. And because of this, I don't know which code to include to illustrate this problem, apart from a snippet from the **form.xml**:

```xml
<field name="categories" component="WeProvide_Specialist/js/components/select-category" sortOrder="60" formElement="select">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="showCheckbox" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <required>true</required>
        <validation>
            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
        </validation>
        <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
        <label translate="true">Categories</label>
        <dataScope>data.customer</dataScope>
        <componentType>field</componentType>
        <listens>
            <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
        </listens>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <select>
            <settings>
                <options class="WeProvide\Specialist\Ui\Component\Form\Categories\Options"/>
            </settings>
        </select>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

And maybe **Options.php**:

```php
<?php

namespace WeProvide\Specialist\Ui\Component\Form\Categories;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category as CategoryModel;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory as CategoryCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

/**
 * Options tree for "Categories" field
 */
class Options implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var CategoryCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $categoryCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $categoriesTree;

    /**
     * @param CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        CategoryCollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getCategoriesTree();
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function getCategoriesTree()
    {
        if ($this->categoriesTree === null) {
            $storeId = $this->request->getParam('store');
            /* @var $matchingNamesCollection Collection */
            $matchingNamesCollection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $matchingNamesCollection->addAttributeToSelect('path')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['neq' => CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $shownCategoriesIds = [];

            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category */
            foreach ($matchingNamesCollection as $category) {
                foreach (explode('/', $category->getPath()) as $parentId) {
                    $shownCategoriesIds[$parentId] = 1;
                }
            }

            /* @var $collection Collection */
            $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => array_keys($shownCategoriesIds)])
                ->addAttributeToSelect(['name', 'is_active', 'parent_id'])
                ->setStoreId($storeId);

            $categoryById = [
                CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID => [
                    'value' => CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID
                ],
            ];

            foreach ($collection as $category) {
                foreach ([$category->getId(), $category->getParentId()] as $categoryId) {
                    if (!isset($categoryById[$categoryId])) {
                        $categoryById[$categoryId] = ['value' => $categoryId];
                    }
                }

                $categoryById[$category->getId()]['is_active'] = $category->getIsActive();
                $categoryById[$category->getId()]['label'] = $category->getName();
                $categoryById[$category->getParentId()]['optgroup'][] = &$categoryById[$category->getId()];
            }

            $this->categoriesTree = $categoryById[CategoryModel::TREE_ROOT_ID]['optgroup'];
        }

        return $this->categoriesTree;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Please tell if I can elaborate some more.

Thanks